# Does the iPhone multi-task while sending email?

Tags: iphone, sms, multitasking

When I send a message and the progress bar is still "moving", can I simply move along and send another message?

And even before that is completed, if I move along and send another message can I be guaranteed that all messages will be sent?

Comment: Of course it multi tasks - play some iTunes while you text ;-) I really like the SMS app flagging messages that don't actually leave the device. It's not a guaranteed delivery, but at least your carrier got the whole message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's own applications have the capability to do "real" background processing and multitasking. User created applications have "some" capability (and limited time) to perform "certain" background processing and multitasking.

With that said, most apps that need to finish a task, can do so because Apple has provided a way to do such things.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. You can even close the Messaging app.

Comment: Do keep in mind, there's never a guarantee the system won't kill any app at any time. If a low memory event happens, the system jettisons whatever processes it thinks will free up enough memory for the frontmost app. Yes, the SMS app will still keep sending in the background - especially if it's a large attachment using the thin SMS channel. But if you open up a huge app like a game, the chances of low memory killing SMS app goes up so don't switch away if you need a guarantee. In practice you would be hard pressed to stop a text only message unless your carrier is having issues at the time.